# Is it necessary to overload operator in this specific case

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>

class Complex
{
    double *arr;
    int n;

public:
    Complex() :n(0), arr(nullptr) {};
    Complex(const Complex &a)
    {
        if (this != a)
        {
            this->~Complex();
            copy(a);
         }
    }
    void copy(const Complex &a)
    {
        n = a.n;
        arr = new double[n];
        std::copy(a.arr, a.arr + n, arr);

    }
    ~Complex()
    {
        delete[] arr;
        n = 0;
    }
};
int main()
{


    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

This is the code i have, as you can see, all i did so far is that i created class `Complex` and i created default constructor and i wanted to create copy constructor, which shouldn't be complicated, but when i tried to compile this, compiler says  "no operator '!=' matches these operands" , now, i know that `this` is a pointer to the ongoing object, and a is my argument that is sent to function by reference, so i am wondering, do i need to treat this argument inside of a function as a regular variable even though it is sent as a reference? Could that be the problem? Or is it something else? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
if (this != a)
```

is a syntactic error since type of `this` is a pointer while `a` is a reference to an object. A syntactially correct form would be:

```
if (this != &a)
```

However, that is totally unnecessary in a copy constructor. In the copy constructor, you are creating a new object from another object. `this != &a` will always be `true`.

Secondly, don't use

```
this->~Complex();
```

in the function. You have not yet constructed the object. What sense does it make to call the destructor on it? Also, once you have called the destructor, the object is dead. Using the object after that is cause for undefined behavior.

Simlify your function to:

```
Complex(const Complex &a)
{
   copy(a);
}
```

Comment: Just copying and pasting from the OP's post.

Answer (score 2):

A constructor's job is to initialize an object under creation. There is no pre-existing object there yet, so doing the check `this != &a` is pointless (I fixed it to compare addresses, as you probably meant). The only way that condition will ever be false is if someone writes this Machiavellian piece of code

```
Complex a(a);
```

It's technically allowed but any compiler worth its salt will flag it with a [nice shiny warning](https://wandbox.org/permlink/B7wjXceP5w21EaKs) that this line needs to be fixed.

Now, because there is no object there yet (it is being created), calling its destructor makes your program have undefined behavior. It means you can't predict what will happen according to the C++ specification, which puts you on very shaky ground.

A straight forward constructor will do the job just fine:

```
Complex(const Complex &a) : n(a.n), arr(new double[a.n])
{
    std::copy(a.arr, a.arr + n, arr);
}
```

Protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli. Defensive programming is good to stop someone from accidentally braking your code. But you can't stop someone intent on it, so don't write overly complex checks to try.

Comment: I think this is a bad answer

Answer (score 1):

No, in `if (this != a)` you have `this` that is a pointer and `a` that is a reference.

Do: `if (this != &a)`

Comment: ....   assuming that the class doesn't supply an overload of unary `operator&()` which returns something different that the address of the object.

Comment: I don't need to assume, do I? The class does not supply such an overload.